# Querying application stats with aggregate by

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am migrating code to v2.2 of the API and need to separate the clicks/impressions between unique and non unique.

The [API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/app_insights) ask us to pass count and uu as values for the aggregateBy modifier which if i pass uu it returns an error->

```
/v2.2/appid12345/app_insights/story_impressions?aggregateBy=uu

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Param aggregateBy must be one of {COUNT, USERS, TOPK, SUM, USD_SUM, UNKNOWN_USERS}", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

But if i pass USERS as the error message states i get json returned

```
/v2.2/appid12345/app_insights/story_impressions?aggregateBy=USERS

{
  "data": [
    {
      "time": "2015-01-15T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "56"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2015-01-16T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "128"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2015-01-17T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "196"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2015-01-18T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "420"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2015-01-19T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "304"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2015-01-20T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "176"
    }, 
    {
      "time": "2015-01-21T08:00:00+0000", 
      "value": "128"
    }
  ]
}
```

My questions is- **can i assume the USERS value with the modifier returns the unique  count? and the COUNT values returns the non unique?**

Comment: File a bug report against the documentation, which appears to be incorrect based on your question here

Answer (score 0):

Its been reported to facebook as a bug

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412068288957160/